# UIButtons in UITableViewCell do not show textLabel changes until cells scroll off screen

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, uibutton

I have a UIViewController with a calendar and below it is a UITableView with a UITableViewCell that has a series of UIButtons that I change the button text depending on the data that I retrieve. When a date is selected I update a NSArray and call [self.tableView reloadData].  The first row populates as it should, the UIButton titles show the correct data.  The rest of the rows show the default values for the UIButtons from the storyboard.  If I scroll a cell off the screen and let it come back it displays the correct data (i.e. updates the titles of the UIButtons).  I'm not sure why this is happening. I tried adding 
[cell setNeedsLayout] before the cell is returned but it has not helped.

Comment: Are you modifying the testLabels directly? UIButtons have iffy behavior sometimes if you do. Try using the UIButton methods to change the textLabel's properties, such as setTitle: forState:

Comment: Good suggestion but it didn't solve the problem.

Comment: @Aderis Actually your suggestion did work.  I made a mistake in how I implemented it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you modifying the testLabels directly? UIButtons have iffy behavior sometimes if you do. Try using the UIButton methods to change the textLabel's properties, such as setTitle: forState: